# Color Blend in BezierCurve

Tags: graphics, color, splines

How can I color a `BezierCurve` from `Red` into `Green` just as `Line` does?

```
pts={{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,0}};
Graphics[{Thick, BezierCurve[pts], Line[{{0,0}, {2,0}}, VertexColors->{Red, Green}]}]
```

[image: spLine]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple line strip should be sufficient for most purposes and there you can use `VertexColors` as usual:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}};
Graphics[{Thick, 
  Line[BezierFunction[pts] /@ #, 
    VertexColors -> (Blend[{Red, Green}, #] & /@ #)] &[Range[0, 1, .01]], 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: This was what I was looking for. tks

Answer (score 11):

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}};
f = BezierFunction[pts];
Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, RGBColor[1 - x, x, 0]]], 
 Graphics[{Thick,Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}], Axes -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]