# Visualize an irrational number

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, visualization, generative-art

I would like to visualize an irrational number like the square root of 2 with *Mathematica*. I found this visualization of `Pi` in the internet and wonder how this would be done with *Mathematica*. The image shows the connection of each digit with its following digit.

[image: Pi Visualiztaion]

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: FYI: This kind of plot is called Circular Migration Flow plots.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With a pie chart around it:

```
clusterSector[gap_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, y_}, rest___] := 
 Block[{ngap = Min[(xmax - xmin)/2, gap]},
  {EdgeForm[White], 
   ChartElementData["Sector"][{{xmin + ngap, xmax - ngap}, y}, rest]}];

iCoord[{i_, j_}, bin_: 60] := 
  Through[{Cos, Sin}[
    Pi/2 - \[Pi]/5 i  - (\[Pi]/5)/bin (j - 1) - 0.025]];

iCurve[{x_, y_}, rad_: 15, bin_: 60, colorf_: ColorData[35]] := 
 Block[{s, t, range, c1, c2},
  {s, t} = iCoord[#, bin] & /@ {x, y};
  {c1, c2} = colorf /@ {x[[1]], y[[1]]};
  range = Range[0, 1, .1];
  Line[BezierFunction[rad {s, {0, 0} + .4  Normalize[(s + t)], t}] /@ 
    range, VertexColors -> (Blend[{c1, c2}, #] & /@ range)]]

digits = First@RealDigits[Sqrt[2], 10, 1000];
count = Association[Thread[Range[0, 9] -> Table[1, 10]]];
cdigits = Partition[{#, count[#]++} & /@ digits, 2, 1];
bin = Max[cdigits];

curves = iCurve[#, 15.5, bin, ColorData[35]] & /@ cdigits;

Show[{PieChart[Table[1, 10], 
   SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 16}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
   ChartElementFunction -> clusterSector[0.02], 
   ChartLabels -> 
    Placed[Table[
      Rotate[Style[i, 15, White, 
        FontFamily -> "Arials"], -(18 + 36 i)  Degree], {i, 0, 
       9}], {1/2, 1.8}], ChartStyle -> 35, Background -> Black], 
  Graphics[{{Opacity[.4], curves}, 
    Text[Style[ToString[Sqrt[2], StandardForm], White, 30, Bold], {0, 
      0}]}]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Manipulate the sequence:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{PieChart[Table[1, 10], 
    SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 16}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
    ChartElementFunction -> clusterSector[0.02], 
    ChartLabels -> 
     Placed[Table[
       Rotate[Style[i, 20, White, 
         FontFamily -> "Arials"], -(18 + 36 i)  Degree], {i, 0, 
        9}], {1/2, 1.8}], ChartStyle -> 35, Background -> Black], 
   Graphics[{{Opacity[.4], curves[[;; n]]}, 
     Text[Style[ToString[Sqrt[2], StandardForm], White, 30, Bold], {0,
        0}]}]}, ImageSize -> 600]
 , {n, 0, Length[cdigits], 1}]
```

[image: graphics]

Comment: PieChart part is quite smart! :)

Comment: Thank you bro. This is awesome. It just looks like the picture i posted. Thanks alot again!!

Comment: Nice :) p.s. with weighting colors in favor of starting point it starts to mix similarly to op's example: e.g. `Blend[{c1, c2}, #/7.] &`

Answer (score 29):

With help of:

(1) [how to generate repeatable Unique streams?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103751/5478)

(2) [Color Blend in BezierCurve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29536/5478)

(3) [Is it possible to draw really thin lines in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66178/5478)

here is something to start:

```
ClearAll[pos];

  (*(1)*)
mem : pos[n_] := mem = Module[{i = 2. Pi  n/10}, 
   Through[{Sin, Cos, Identity}[i += 2. Pi/10.^3.]] &
] 

col = Blend["TemperatureMap", #/(2. Pi)] &;

arcs = With[{
   range = Range[0, 1, .1], 
   p1 = #[[;; 2]], p2 = #2[[;; 2]], 
   c1 = col[#[[3]]], c2 = col[#2[[3]]]
  },
  Line[ (*(2)*)
   BezierFunction[{p1, {0, 0} + .3 Normalize[(p1 + p2)], p2}] /@ range,
   VertexColors -> (Blend[{c1, c2}, #] & /@ range)
  ]
] & @@@ Partition[
    pos[#][] & /@ First@RealDigits[Pi, 10, 900],
    2, 1
];

Graphics[{ (*(3)*)
  Opacity[.3], AbsoluteThickness[0], arcs, 
  Thick, White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.05]
  }, ImageSize -> 1000, Background -> Black
]
```

[image]

```
...Blend[{c1, c2}, #/5]...
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The plot you show gives the digits of π in a directed graph, [this](https://www.visualnews.com/2013/07/09/the-art-of-pi-a-colorful-data-visualization/) *may* be the original source.

You can do this with *Mathematica* by using `RealDigits` to get the digits of the numbers, and then using `Partition` to split it into pairs, and then feeding the result into `Graph`.  Here is a graph of the first 50 digits of `Sqrt[2]`.

```
vertices = Range[0, 9];
edgerules = Rule @@@ Partition[
    First@RealDigits[Sqrt[2], 10, 50], 2, 1];
vertexcoords = CirclePoints[10];
Graph[vertices, edgerules, VertexCoordinates -> vertexcoords, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", LabelStyle -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This doesn't look exactly like your plot, but it's the same basic idea.  You could work out the coloring perhaps using `EdgeShapeFunction`.  Increasing the number of digits to 5000 gives this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't particularly care for this method of visualizing the digits, as I think any non-repeating decimal representation will end up looking the same.

It does look pretty neat if you animate it though,

[image: Mathematica graphics]